# Java String - Fetching other languages character from mysql - Is the data complete?

Tags: java, mysql, string, special-characters

Is the Java String data that I will fetch complete if I have special characters like japanese, greek, chinese, korean, etc. characters stored in my mysql database?

To be clear my question is will the special characters that I fetched in mysql complete if I stored them in java string, and will I able to display them in character form when I use them for text components like JEditorPane

```
     String data;
     ResultSet r = sabiNa.executeQuery();
     while(r.next()) {
         data = r.getString("data");
     }
```

Comment: This is presumably a question about Java's support for Unicode characters?

Comment: edited the question. Yep it is about the unicode characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is capable of storing ALL valid Unicode text. It uses UTF-16 internally.

If you configure the entire data path correctly, all text will be preserved. You need to ensure:

- The correct string reaches Java (in case of web applications, character encoding of the form being submitted).
- Java knows it should be talking to the database in UTF-8 and the database knows it should be expecting UTF-8 through the connection. You ensure this when setting up the database connection.
- Data is stored as UTF-8 in the database.

Note that [the documentation for MySQL] *claims* UTF-8 is incapable of storing characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (all "normal" characters lie within BMP). UTF-8 itself is perfectly capable of storing all unicode characters and the database should be able to encode these characters as well.

Java itself is fine - just remember some rare unicode characters are actually two characters (called a [surrogate pair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/supplementaryChars.html)) in Java.