# How to embed gujarati sqlite database file and show in textview into an android app?

Tags: android

I want to embed gujarati sqlite database file into application and I want to showing it in textview in gujarati font. I have already created an SQLite database in gujarati. I inserted my database file and fonts into the assests folder.

```
package com.shreemadbhagwatgeeta;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Geeta_Data extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static String TAG="SQLiteOpenHelper";

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Shreemad_Bhagwat_Geeta";
    public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.shreemadbhagwatgeeta/databases/";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context dbContext;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper database;
    private boolean createDatabase = false;
    private boolean upgradeDatabase = false;

    public Geeta_Data(Context context) throws SQLException {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.dbContext = context;

        if (checkDataBase()) {
            openDataBase();
            Log.i(TAG, "checkDataBase()");
        } else
        {
            try {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                copyDataBase();
                this.close();
                openDataBase();

                Log.i(TAG, "copyDataBase()");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Initial database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("db log", "database does't exist");
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            exist = true;
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return exist;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createDatabase = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        upgradeDatabase = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store those strings.

Sqlite always works with unicode strings. Java String is also unicode. So everything should work out of the box. If it does not, than say what that is.

Internally sqlite encodes all strings either in utf-8 or utf-16 (there is a per-database option), but since it always converts them as needed (to one or other for comparison and to/from java.lang.String in the API), you don't even need to care.

https://uwudamith.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/how-to-insert-unicode-values-to-mysql-using-java/

[Java String - Fetching other languages character from mysql - Is the data complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085133/java-string-fetching-other-languages-character-from-mysql-is-the-data-comple)